# Mirror Create Player From Client and Change Scene

Tags: unity, multiplayer, mirror-networking

I'm very new to Mirror in Unity but I have a lot of experience in Network-programing.

I'm currently trying to create a Game, where the Player's data is stored on the client, and can join different games (not concurrent) with his/her character. (Likely to Terraria)

So I can't use the automatic Player creation of the default NetworkManager class. After clicking "Join/Host" in our Main-Menu I want to change to the scene the player has played in, Hosting/joining a server and create the player on the server with the specific position...

I have tried now multiple attempts to do this, but none of mine seemed to work.
Am I the even possible to have the players in different scenes with ease?
Where/When should I create the Player so isn't null on the Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom NetworkManager and just handle the spawning/ setting there. But keep in mind if you trust the client with the players data, it is open to manipulation.

```
public class BasicNetwork: NetworkManager
{            
    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        Transform startPos = GetStartPosition();
        GameObject player = startPos != null
            ? Instantiate(playerPrefab, startPos.position, startPos.rotation)
            : Instantiate(playerPrefab);
        player.GetComponent<Player>().playerName = "Player " + Random.Range(0, 1000);
        //Gives the client authority
        NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, player);
    }
}
```

In the Room Example from Mirror you can find another example for passing data from the Roomplayer to the Player located in the `OnRoomServerSceneLoadedForPlayer` (which could be used if I understand your question correctly). Your RoomPlayer is like a Lobby and you could make a custom loading from your local clients data there - even if it is like a 1 Personlobby to get ready.